# How to backup, restore and share Android settings on a multi-user system?

Tags: settings, backup, multi-user, android-10, systemless-root

I have a `Magisk`-rooted `Android 10` device. I want to:

- backup my `Owner` user settings;
- clone some settings (background images, sounds, vibrations, etc.) from `Owner` local user to other users (`Work`, `Guest`, etc.);
- use only built-in or open-source 3rd-party tools.

What are the options available?

Comment: I am not sure in which package the different settings you want to backup are located in, but a good backup program like [OAndBackupX](https://github.com/machiav3lli/oandbackupx) should cover most or all of your needs. Note: restoring a backup of system apps (such as Android settings) on a different device type than the one it has been taken from can have strange side in case options are not shown in the GUI but the restored settings are still active. Therefore restoring the settings on a different device is not recommended.

Comment: @Robert thank you for suggesting this app. What do I actually do in it to perform the tasks in my question?

Comment: I would assume that all those values you want to backup are located in the android settings app. Therefore backup the data of the app `com.android.settings`.